# Phalcon and Lumen integration

Tags: integration, phalcon, lumen

I have site on phalcon. I want do system of auth, profiles and comments on framework Lumen. I can integrate auth and profiles, comments system on framework Phalcon?

Example: 
I do system on Lumen on domain: api.example.com
But site on framework phalcon on: example.com

I can integrate system profiles, auth and comments with api.example.com, where lumen? Or not?

Comment: Yes! You can use Phalcon with any other framework. The question should you, depends on the problem you want to solve and it's really opinion based :)

Comment: I want do authentication on first in phalcon with lumen. How I can do this?